# popup window for aspx.net usercontrol

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am using two user control of asp.net in my aspx page. I have a if condition in one of my user control where i am making a decision , base of the decision i want to open a popup window. Any help will be precipitated.

Comment: Why is your question tagged with `asp.net-mvc`? Are you using ASP.NET MVC or classic ASP.NET WenForms? Also why `jquery-ajax`?

Comment: yes i am using ASP.net MVC with Jquery-ajax ( ajax for only popup window)

Comment: Then why are you talking about user controls? There's no such notion in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Answer.

RegisterStartupScript or RegisterClientScriptBlock method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx[^]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx[^]

I used registerClinetScriptBlock method and its work.

Comment: I don't understand how this is MVC. Where do call RegisterStartupScript or RegisterClientScriptBlock?

Comment: Completely agree. This is not ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: i am sorry guys, i just red my reply to MVC. I am not using MVC.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show PopUp" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>




    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
    }
```